# Client Server Program String leak?

Tags: java

My Server Program:-

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;


public class GetFileServeredit implements Runnable {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4747;
    public String FileName=null; 
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket svr=new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            while(true){
                System.out.println("S: Waiting...");

                Socket sktClient=svr.accept();
                System.out.println("S: Receiving...");
                try{

                    PrintService services[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

                    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sktClient.getOutputStream())),true);

                    /*for(int z=0;z<services.length;z++){

                        out2.println(services[z]);

                    }*/
                    out2.println("aaa 12212");
                    out2.flush();
                    out2.close();

                    sktClient.close();

                    System.out.println("Transfer complete.");


                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Thread servThread =new Thread(new GetFileServeredit());
        servThread.start();
    }
}
```

My Client Program
:-

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ClientPrinters implements Runnable {
    static final int PORT = 4747; //Change this to the relevant port
    static final String HOST = "192.***.*.***"; //Change this to the relevant HOST,//(where Server.java is running)

    public void run() {

        try {
            System.out.print("Sending data...\n");
            Socket skt = new Socket(HOST, PORT);        

            ArrayList Printers =new ArrayList();
            InputStream inStream = skt.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader inm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));


            while ((inm.read()) != -1) {
                Printers.add(inm.readLine());
            }


            inm.close();
            inStream.close();
            skt.close();

            }
        catch( Exception e ) {          
            System.out.print("Error! It didn't work! " + e + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Thread cThread =new Thread(new ClientPrinters());
        cThread.start();
    }
}
```

The out that i am sending form the server i.e

```
out2.println("aaa 12212");
```

becomes 12212 only at the client side,why? where is the other text??

Comment: That's strange. I receive `aa 12212` at the client side. But this is perfectly understandable, because the first byte is silently discarded by calling `inm.read()`. Note that [`BufferedReader::readLine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) reads from the current position until the end of the line. It does not go back to the start of the line before reading

Comment: note: `PrintWriter` methods do not throw IOExceptions, you may miss some since not calling `checkError`. Probably not the actual problem, but I'd suggest not using `PrintWriter` for such an application.

Comment: @Carlos so what should i use??

Comment: just the `BufferedWritter` (or check the results from `checkError°)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you intended was

```
List<String> printers =new ArrayList<String>();
String line; 
while ((line = inm.readLine()) != null)
    printers.add(line);
```

Note: use camelCase for field/variable names.

Comment: bt it says use line as int instead of string??

Comment: @Harinder, what says this? It compiles fine for me. There are no `int` values in this code.

Comment: Thks a Lot..problm soved!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((inm.read()) != -1) {
    Printers.add(inm.readLine());
}
```

This line **first** reads a single  and *if* that succeeds, it tries to read a line. This swallows (and ignores) one character per line.

Also: you don't specify any character encodings in your server and client: This will work (with some restrictions) as long as client and server run using the same locale. But it will break once they use different default encodings.

It's probably best to just specify the encoding to use "on the wire". A great candidate for this is UTF-8:

```
// server
PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sktClient.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")),true);

// client
BufferedReader inm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I was not running your code,but. 
while ((inm.read()) != -1) {
}

I think .read() consumed some byte.

you should use some buffer(byte[]) and call .read(buffer)!=-1